# Is there a public SQL database for all US stocks?

Tags: data, programming

I would like to search through all US stocks (via SQL or another technology), and filter them by certain parameters (similar to a [stock screener](http://finviz.com/screener.ashx), but through an API rather than a user interface). Is there such API/WebService that will offer me a database of up-to-date US stocks, or allow me to search stocks by properties such as P/E ratio?

Comment: There are and they cost money depending on how up-to-date you need your information and what information you are looking for.  One of the most comprehensive would be to get a Bloomberg account.